# Reading Data from TCP port of embedded device

Tags: sockets, networking, ip, embedded-linux, tcp

I want to read data from the specific TCP port of the embedded device and then send it to a server. So my whole device has a sensor attached to the board and that sensor sends some data on the TCP port 6000 for example. My code looks like

```
// create socket
int sockrd = socket(AF_INET, SOCK_STREAM,0);

if(sockrd < 0)
{
    std::cout<<"Can't create socket\n"<<std::endl;
    exit(1);
}

// Name and bind socket
struct sockaddr_in addressrd;
addressrd.sin_family = AF_INET;
addressrd.sin_addr.s_addr = inet_addr("127.0.0.1");//Provide ip of the board
addressrd.sin_port=htons(6000); // TCP port of the board

bind(sockrd,(struct sockaddr*)&addressrd, sizeof(addressrd));

if(bind < 0)
{
    std::cout<<"Can't bind properly\n"<<std::endl;
}

// declare a buffer to read from the tcp port of the device
char buffer[1024];
read(sockrd,&buffer,sizeof(buffer));
close(sockrd);
```

I don't have to worry about the server process. I am struggling to understand how to do it with respect to the embedded device only, which means only my Embedded device reads data from its respective tcp port and then send it to server. My code will run on the processor on the board which has embedded linux inside.

Comment: Show your code and explain what it does and doesn't do. If you don't have any code, start by reading a tutorial.

Answer (score 0):

You're trying to read from an unconnected port. It will fail. You need to either:

- `connect()` *to* the peer, in which case you don't need the `bind()`, or
- `listen()` at the port and `accept()` a connection *from* the peer.

Which is correct depends on the device. At present you're doing neither.

The present `bind()` call, binding to 127.0.0.1, will prevent all connectivity to or from outside, and should be removed if you're the client, or altered to bind to INADDR_ANY if you're the server.

You also need to add error-checking to your `read()` call, and fix the other error checks so they call `perror()` or friends, so you get the actual failure modes, not some useless message of your own devising.

Comment: I want my board to act as a client (it reads data coming on its tcp port and then send it to the server). I have problems only in understanding  how to read data from the device itself. Since the code will run on the processor after development. So, just assume that my embedded device which has severals sensors attached on one board and send data on tcp port 6000 I need to read that data and den later connect to server. The part you mentioned is generic of a client server model, which I do understand.

Comment: You may understand it, but you haven't implemented it. You are reading from an unconnected socket. It will fail. If the board is the client, it has to connect to the server. But I think you've missed something from your description. It seems to me that your code is also a TCP server to the board, so you have to accept a connection from the board. Or else it is a client of the board and you have to connect to it. Whatever the case, you have to do one or the other.

Comment: Yes you are right. So, I am thinking of this scenario right now:                          I will run a client program on the board as well as server program. The server program will be binded to board's ip with port number 6000. My client program will receive data from the server. The issue I am facing is how can I send the received data on port 6000 to another server? I  think I need a shared queue in this case between two clients. Am I right ?

Comment: I think you have it all back to front. The board should be a *server* that will send data to anybody who connects to it. If nobody connects, no sending. That makes configuration simpler too: you don't have to tell the board what to connect to, only its own port number.

Comment: You are right, but as a client I should receive data from the board and send it to another server. So the scenario is like receiving data from one server as a client and passing that data to another server. Are there any general solutions to this thing? I am thinking of a shared queue.

Comment: I don't see why you need a queue. Just connect a socket to the board, another to the server, read from the board, send what you read to the server. No queue required. Just a simple bog-standard copy loop.